# touchesMoved move background image

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

**Current Situation**

View loads, loads backgroundImage
Shows the `reticle BOOL` as false

```
-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    /* Setup your scene here */
    self.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
    self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:0.15 green:0.15 blue:0.3 alpha:1.0];
    //Add background
    NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"backgroundTemp" ofType:@"png"];
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:bundle];
    SKTexture *texture = [SKTexture textureWithImage:image];
    backgroundImage = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:texture];
    backgroundImage.size = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
    backgroundImage.position = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
    backgroundImage.zPosition = 0;
    [self addChild:backgroundImage];
    //END Add Background

    removeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    reticleShow = false;

}
```

So after the background image has been loaded, displayed. The only other option is to press the screen to result in an enlargement of `backgroundImage` as well as loading the `reticle` image.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    /* Called when a touch begins */
    if (reticleShow == false) {
        //Add Reticle
        NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"reticle_001" ofType:@"png"];
        UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:bundle];
        SKTexture *texture = [SKTexture textureWithImage:image];
        SKSpriteNode *reticle = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:texture];
        reticle.zPosition = 1;
        reticle.size = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
        reticle.position = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
        [self addChild:reticle];

        [removeArray addObject:reticle];
        //End Add Reticle

        //Enlarge background
        backgroundImage.size = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width*3, self.frame.size.height*3);
        //End Enlarge background

        reticleShow = true;
    } else {
//        //Remove reticle
//        backgroundImage.size = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
//        [self removeChildrenInArray:removeArray];
//        reticleShow = false;
//        //end remove reticle

        //enable drag

        //end enable drag
    }
}
```

Now that provides the enlargement and the boolean prevents from further sprites being added, as well as providing the reticle image.

Now, after this has loaded. Or the initial press has been made. I now want to be able to drag the background. i.e move the background and keep the reticle centred.

So I've made this,

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
        SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];

        if ([node.name isEqualToString:backgroundImage]) { <--- ERROR HERE sksprite node to type nsstring

            CGPoint previousLocation = [touch previousLocationInNode:self];
            float diff = location.y - previousLocation.y;
            CGPoint newPosition = CGPointMake(node.position.x, node.position.y +diff);

            if (newPosition.y > 230) {
                newPosition.y = 230;
            }
            node.position = newPosition;
        }
    }
}
```

**Three questions**

1. How to drag an image on a lesser z-index? i.e drag background instead of reticle?
2. How to move the background image after it has been enlarged?
3. *How to pass the sknode & nsstring error?* backgroundImage.name = @"backgroundImage";

Comment: 3 - SKNode has a name property. You need to set it. For example, myNode.name = @"myName"; then you check for it by using if([myNode.name isEqualToString:@"myName"])

Comment: @sangony Excellent, that answered one of my questions. Thank you

Comment: @sangony now I can move the background on z-index 0 however, if the reticle z-index 1 is overlayed, I cannot move the backgroundimage.

Comment: If the node(s) which have a higher zPosition than your background do not require user interaction, such as touch events, set their userInteractionEnabled property to NO.

Answer (score 0):

**Question One**
Drag on lesser Z-Index

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
        SKNode *node = [backgroundImage nodeAtPoint:location];

        if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"backgroundImage"]) {

            CGPoint previousLocation = [touch previousLocationInNode:self];
            float ydiff = location.y - previousLocation.y;
            float xdiff = location.x - previousLocation.x;
            CGPoint newPosition = CGPointMake(node.position.x - xdiff, node.position.y - ydiff);

            if (newPosition.y > 230) {
                newPosition.y = 230;
            }
            node.position = newPosition;
        }
    }
}
```

Insert this
`reticle.userInteractionEnabled = NO;`

**Question Two**

Doesn't affect it by enlarging

**Question Three**

Naming the SkSpriteNode for detection

`backgroundImage.name = @"backgroundImage";`